# ASP.NET URL Encoding/Decoding

Tags: asp.net, url, encoding, decoding

I have two files htmlpage1.htm and webform1.aspx

htmlpage1.htm contains a anchor tag with href="webform1.aspx?name=abc+xyz".

When i try to access the querystring in page_load of webform1.aspx, i get "abc xyz" (abc [space] xyz). I want exact value in querystring "abc+xyz"

**Note:** href value cannot be changed

Any help will be appreciated

Thank You.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will Server.UrlDecode for you:

```
Request.QueryString["name"] // "abc xyz"
```

Option 1) You can re-encode

```
Server.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["name"]); // "abc+xyz"
```

or get the raw query data

```
Request.Url.Query // "?name=abc+xyz"
```

Option 2) Then parse the value

```
Request.Url.Query.Substring(Request.Url.Query.IndexOf("name=") + 5) // "abc+xyz"
```

Answer (score 1):

ASP.net will decode the query string for your.  you can get the raw query string and parse it yourself if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try `webform1.aspx?name=abc%2Bxyz`

Comment: @Faizal In that case, if you don't expect space in your `name` query parameter, just replace space with `+`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :
Request.QueryString["name"].Replace(" ","+");
// Refer below link for more info
http://runtingsproper.blogspot.in/2009/10/why-aspnet-accidentally-corrupts-your.html